# Powershell RunAs Administrator in a SSIS Package

Tags: powershell, ssis, powershell-remoting

Am trying to remote connect to a server and run a powershell script to open ports in windows firewall in a SSIS Execute Process task[image]

**Here is the Powershell code:**

```
$computername = hostname

$script = {
$FireWallRule_1 = Get-NetFirewallRule
    $par1 = @{
    DisplayName = "DAC"
    LocalPort = 1434
    Direction="Inbound"
    Protocol ="TCP" 
    Action = "Allow"
}
$FireWallRule_2 = Get-NetFirewallRule
    $par2 = @{
    DisplayName = "MSSQLSERVER"
    LocalPort = 1433
    Direction="Inbound"
    Protocol ="TCP" 
    Action = "Allow"
}

$par1.Localport = 1434
$par1.DisplayName = "DAC"
if (-not $FireWallRule_1.DisplayName.Contains($par1.DisplayName)) {New-NetFirewallRule @par1}

$par2.LocalPort = 1433
$par2.DisplayName = "MSSQLSERVER"
if (-not $FireWallRule_2.DisplayName.Contains($par2.DisplayName)) {New-NetFirewallRule @par2}

}

Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $script -ComputerName $computername
```

**Here is the error i got:**

> *Connecting to remote server [SERVERNAME] failed with the following error message: Access is denied. For more information, see the
>   aboute_Remote_Troubleshooting Helptopic.
>   + CategoryInfo : OpenError: (SERVERNAME:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
>   + FullyQualifiederrorId : AccessDenied, PSSessionStateBroken*

I have tried to run the PS script locally and its working, the account that run ssis is local administrator on the target server. Is it possible to RunAs Administrator in a SSIS Package?

Thanks Håkan